# How to display the details of a row from multiple tables using LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm stuck here on a situation wherein I should display the details of a person together with the list of his/her allocations. I've done creating a view model to pass the data to a view but the result is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[EKCMIDTA.ViewModels.EmployeeDetailsVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'EKCMIDTA.ViewModels.EmployeeDetailsVM'.

For the **TicketScannings** table, I just wanted to know whether the person has used some of the allocations, and to count how many were used, regardless it it's null.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks!

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int empId)
{
    var employeeInformation = identityContext.AspNetUsers.Find(empId);

    var employeeDetails = dbContext.TicketAllocations.Include(a => a.AllocationCategory).Where(t => t.CMId == empId).ToList();

    var query = (from alloc in dbContext.TicketAllocations
                 join scan in dbContext.TicketScannings
                 on alloc.Id equals scan.TicketAllocationId
                 join card in dbContext.CardNumberAssignments
                 on alloc.CMId equals card.CMId into a
                 from card in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join reserve in dbContext.ReservedCardNumbers
                 on card.CardNumberId equals reserve.Id into b
                 from reserve in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where (alloc.CMId == empId)
                 select new EmployeeDetailsVM()
                 {
                     Employee = new Employee()
                     {
                         FirstName = employeeInformation.FirstName,
                         LastName = employeeInformation.LastName,
                         CMId = employeeInformation.Id,
                         CardNumber = reserve == null ? "No Card Number yet" : reserve.CardNumber,
                         QRCode = card == null ? "No QR Code yet" : card.QRCode
                     },

                     GetTicketAllocations = employeeDetails
                 });

      return View(query);
```

**View Model:**

```
public class EmployeeDetailsVM
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Allocation> GetTicketAllocations { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string CMId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string QRCode { get; set; }
}

public class Allocation
{
    public int AllocationId { get; set; }
    public string AllocationName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model EKCMIDTA.ViewModels.EmployeeDetailsVM
```

Comment: using foreign key could make it easier

Comment: @JephrenNaicker hi, Thank you for your response. But I have foreign keys on the tables that's why I can join them on their reference Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your view is only accepting a model of a single `EmployeeDetailsVM`, but you're passing in a query which would could return multiple.

so you can change `@model EKCMIDTA.ViewModels.EmployeeDetailsVM` to `@model IEnumerable<EKCMIDTA.ViewModels.EmployeeDetailsVM>`

or change your `GetDetails` action to `return View(query.FirstOrDefault());`

**Edit based on comment**

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int empId)
{
    var employeeInformation = identityContext.AspNetUsers.Find(empId);

    var employeeTickets = dbContext.TicketAllocations.Include(a => a.AllocationCategory).Where(t => t.CMId == empId).ToList();

    var employeeDetails = (from alloc in dbContext.TicketAllocations
                 join scan in dbContext.TicketScannings
                 on alloc.Id equals scan.TicketAllocationId
                 join card in dbContext.CardNumberAssignments
                 on alloc.CMId equals card.CMId into a
                 from card in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join reserve in dbContext.ReservedCardNumbers
                 on card.CardNumberId equals reserve.Id into b
                 from reserve in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where (alloc.CMId == empId)
                 select new EmployeeDetailsVM()
                 {
                     Employee = new Employee()
                     {
                         FirstName = employeeInformation.FirstName,
                         LastName = employeeInformation.LastName,
                         CMId = employeeInformation.Id,
                         CardNumber = reserve == null ? "No Card Number yet" : reserve.CardNumber,
                         QRCode = card == null ? "No QR Code yet" : card.QRCode
                     }
                 }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (employeeDetails != null)
        employeeDetails.GetTicketAllocations = employeeTickets;

    return View(employeeDetails);
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help! But I am now encountering a new error which is 

Unable to create a constant value of type 'EKCMIDTA.Models.TicketAllocation'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

It turns out that the `return View(query.FirstOrDefault());` line is the error.

Comment: try moving the `GetTicketAllocations` part out of the query.  See edit

Comment: hi. thank you for the resolution! you just saved my day!

Comment: @PaoloDevoma you're welcome.. you should check for null when using `FirstOrDefault()` as the `Default` is null